# How do I show this hyperbolic identity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to derive

$$y = \exp \left(\dfrac{a+b}2t \right) \left(k_1 \cosh \left(\dfrac{(a-b)t}2 \right) + k_2 \sinh \left(\dfrac{(a-b)t}2 \right) \right)$$

From $$y = c_1 \exp(at) + c_2 \exp(bt)$$

I've managed to get the $ \exp \left ( \dfrac{a+b}2t \right)\cosh \left ( \dfrac{(a-b)t}{2} \right) $ part, but I cannot the hyperbolic sine part because of the minus sign. Remember, I am going from $y = c_1 \exp(at) + c_2 \exp(bt)$ to $y = \exp \left(\dfrac{a+b}2t \right) \left(k_1 \cosh \left(\dfrac{(a-b)t}2 \right) + k_2 \sinh \left(\dfrac{(a-b)t}2 \right) \right)$, not the other way around

Comment: Could you please state more clearly what your constants c1,c2,k1 and k2 mean?

Comment: They are real numbers, I suspect that during the transformation, the $c_1, c_2$ will become new constants $k_1, K_2$.

Comment: I don't understahd what you want: there are two $\,y'$s there: what relation do you want to get??

Comment: I've left all the details you might need. I recommend beginning with your first item with the hyperbolic trig functions, reduce to the simplest form, then carefully write out how to reverse the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
y & = c_1 \exp(at) + c_2 \exp(bt) = c_1 \exp\left(\left(\dfrac{a+b}2 + \dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right) + c_2 \exp\left(\left(\dfrac{a+b}2 - \dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right)\\
& = c_1 \exp\left(\left(\dfrac{a+b}2\right)t \right) \exp \left( \left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right) + c_2 \exp\left(\left(\dfrac{a+b}2\right)t \right) \exp \left( -\left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right)\\
& = \exp\left(\left(\dfrac{a+b}2\right)t \right) \left(c_1  \exp \left( \left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right) + c_2 \exp \left(- \left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right) \right)\\
\end{align}
Now recall that
$$\cosh(x) = \dfrac{\exp(x) + \exp(-x)}2$$ and $$\sinh(x) = \dfrac{\exp(x) - \exp(-x)}2$$ Hence, we get that
$$\exp(x) = \cosh(x) + \sinh(x)$$ and $$\exp(-x) = \cosh(x) - \sinh(x)$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
y& = \exp\left(\left(\dfrac{a+b}2\right)t \right) \left(c_1  \exp \left( \left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right) + c_2 \exp \left(- \left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right) \right)\\
& = \exp\left(\left(\dfrac{a+b}2\right)t \right) \left((c_1+c_2) \cosh \left( \left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right) + (c_1 - c_2) \sinh \left( \left(\dfrac{a-b}2 \right)t \right) \right)\\
\end{align}

Comment: you have about three $\sin$ that should be $\sinh$

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks. updated it.

Answer (score 3):

The direction does not matter. From the definitions,
$$ w_1 \cosh ut + w_2 \sinh u t = h_1 e^{ut} + h_2 e^{-ut}    $$

Let's see, 
$$ (w_1 + w_2)/ 2 = h_1, \; \; (w_1 - w_2)/ 2 = h_2,  $$
so that
$$  h_1 + h_2 = w_1, \; \; h_1 - h_2 = w_2.    $$

For you $   u = (a - b)/2.$

You still need to be confident about this sort of thing:
$$    \exp \left(\dfrac{(a-b)t}2 \right) =  \exp \left(\dfrac{at}2 \right)  \exp \left(\dfrac{-bt}2 \right) \, . $$ 
$$    \exp \left(\dfrac{(b-a)t}2 \right) =  \exp \left(\dfrac{bt}2 \right)  \exp \left(\dfrac{-at}2 \right) \, . $$